# Align environment: take exact control of tab position

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

I was wondering if it is possible to take control of the exact position of the tab in an `align` environment.

Like so:

```
\begin{align}[2cm]
A &= x^3 + 14789\\
B &= f^6
\end{align}
```

Which should then place both '=' signs at *exactly* 2cm from the left margin. No matter how long the expressions before and after '=' are.

Does anyone know how to do something like that?

Comment: What happens if the expression before '=' is 5cm long? then your requirement is impossible to be met  I am not sure if I understand your requirement correctly. I think you probably looking for \hspace*{2cm}\begin{alignment}`

Comment: I would only use it in places where it does not cause trouble.

Comment: Try `\hspace*{2cm}\begin{alignment}`. If it works let me know and I will post an explanation. There are also other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following minimal example, the LHS ends at exactly 2cm from the left margin. The use of the `flalign` environment (from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) with an additional alignment operator `&` pushes everything flush to the left margin, while a box of width 2cm leaves the LHS at the correct position.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
\makebox[2cm][r]{$\displaystyle A$} &= x^3 + 14789 & \\
B &= f^6
\end{flalign}
\noindent\rule{2cm}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

Only `A` is set in a 2cm block, since `B` is "short enough". Otherwise, you can set whatever in a 2cm box, regardless of the size.

[`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to identify the text block border.

Comment: I've added a `\displaystyle` that can be relevant if the left hand side has exponents and in other cases.